# Hibernate Validator - @Column(nullable=false) - How to validate persistence annotations?

Tags: hibernate, validation, persistence, nullable, notnull

I am using Hibernate validator for entity validation in my web-app. Hibernate tools generates the entity objects from the database schema with @Column annotation, containing 'nullable = false'.

```
...
@Column(name = "LANG_IDENTIFIER", nullable = false, length = 2)
public String getIdentifier() {
    return this.identifier;
}
...
```

Is there a way to use the validate @Column on being null?
Adding '@NotNull' does the job, but this is not what I want, because then I need to change all my generated classes.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: nullable=false will throw (I'm guessing) a PersistenceException. In your tests you can persist an instance of the entity and assert not null or catch the exception...